# NBuilder - Issue Creating Nested Object

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, nbuilder

I'm trying to create some dummy objects which have a hierachy like this:

```
Post
 |
 ----User
```

Pretty simple.

Here's the code:

```
var user = Builder<User>.CreateNew().Build();
var posts  = Builder<Post>.CreateListOfSize(100)
                .All()
                .With(x => x.User == user)
                .Build();
```

But for each item, `post.User` is null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

should it be?

```
.With(x => x.User = user)
```

Comment: HAHAH - too easy :)  me =>> http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_BjW1avGcuos/StdCXBOuWaI/AAAAAAAAA2o/5tG1Dd1bTvk/s400/hillary-cackling.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do similar but couldn't find a way of generating user objects with different values (accepted answer would have same data for all user child objects). I ended up using AutoFixture to do this instead:

```
var fixture = new Fixture {RepeatCount = 100};
var posts = fixture.Repeat(fixture.Create<Post>);
```